# Tcl Expect - Script not terminating for long running spawn

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

I am stuck with an Expect code. This was developed as a generic code to run any shell script as another Unix user in the same host (Just for circumventing the limitation of automation engine which can execute only in a specific OS user)

The script terminates properly if the spawn (invoked as SSH) terminates in short time, i.e. within the timeout.

However, the intended processes can complete at various times depending on the data involved.

In the case when the child process runs longer that time out, the expect never terminates even if the child process finishes.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#  Program Name         : generic_run_shell_as_user.expect
#
#  Language/Shell       : Tcl EXPECT : (http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)
#
#  Description          : The purpose of this script is to use expect command to execute a shell script as another user 
#
#  Parameters           : <Pre Exec Env File With Path | - > <Shell Script With Path> [<...Shell Script Argument List...>] <Execution User Name> <Password>
#
#  Returns              :  Return Values   : Return code of the job run
#  Called
#  scripts/programs     : None
#
#  Called from
#  scripts/programs     : Job scheduler
#
#  Execute Mode
#  (batch/interactive)  : Batch
#
#  Author               : 
#
#  Date written         : 24-Sep-2016
#
#  Modification history :
#  Description of change                Date            Modified by
#  ---------------------                -----           -----------
set usage "$argv0 Environment_File_With_Path Shell_Script_With_Path Shell_Script_Argument_List_Optional Execution_User_Name Password"
set timeout 60
set success_code 0
set failure_code 255
#Check Number of Arguments being passed
if { [llength $argv] < 4} {
    puts "Usage : $usage";
    exit $failure_code
}
#Get the hostname , as script is running as 
set host_name [exec hostname]
set arg_last_indx [expr [llength $argv]-1]
set env_file [lindex $argv 0]
if {$env_file == "-"} {
    set env_file_exec ""
} else {
    set env_file_exec ". $env_file &&"
}
#puts $env_file_exec
set script [lindex $argv 1]
set username [lindex $argv [expr $arg_last_indx-1]]
set passwd [lindex $argv $arg_last_indx]
# remove the last two (user name / password) and then the first 2 elements (env file and script) from the arg list
set argv_nw [lreplace [lreplace $argv [expr $arg_last_indx-1] $arg_last_indx] 0 1]
#invoke ssh and connect with new user ,give the env file execution and the script execution with trimmed list as arguments
spawn ssh $username@$host_name $env_file_exec sh $script $argv_nw \r\n

# in case if remote server key is not already imported. reply to the prompt for adding as yes
expect "yes/no" { 
                 send "yes\r\n"
                 }
#pass the input password as reply for the password prompt (handle case of Password and password)                 
expect "*?assword" {  
                   send "$passwd\r"                
                 }
#if the password is wrong , exit citing wrong password               
expect "Permission denied, please try again." {
                       puts "Password is wrong";
                       exit $failure_code
                 }               
expect eof               
# wait until the ssh session terminates and capture its exit code                
catch wait result
set exit_code [lindex $result 3]
#print the exit code of script and exit with same code , for invoker to fail
puts "Exit Code of $script : $exit_code"
exit $exit_code
```

Comment: Regarding *"the expect never terminates even if the child process finishes"*, how did you check that the child process has finished?

Comment: @whjm checked it in processed. Also the shell script creates its own log , every time it logs finished time also in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command takes an arbitrary time, reset the timeout before expecting eof:

```
set timeout -1
expect eof
```

Comment: This cannot explain why *"the expect never terminates even if the child process finishes"*. If `expect eof` times out, the following `wait` will still wait for the spawned process to exit.

Comment: @whjm the child process involves running a shell script which has a exit <exit code> statement in it.

Comment: Facing another issue in case of the child script terminating in short time (Due to error).

**sampleuser@samplehost's password:
expect: 
spawn id exp4 not open
    
while executing
"expect eof                              "

    (file "generic_run_shell_as_user.expect" line 68)**